# how to write relation between three model

Tags: yii

I have three models (tables):

1. content
2. category
3. contentCategory

The `contentCategory` have `content_id` and `category_id` that related to each other.

How I must write relation in each model to select content of specific category?

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
    );
}
```

Comment: if you define the relationship(PK, FK) while designing the database, yii will automatically build the relationship, which is better than defining manually...
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr
the above doc explains cleary about building relations....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table `contentCategory` has only 2 fields `content_id` and `category_id` then u don't need to create a model for this table and in the other models you'll have

Content:

```
'categories'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Category',
                'contentCategory(content_id, category_id)'),
```

Category:

```
'contents'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Content',
                    'contentCategory(category_id, content_id)'),
```

If your table `contentCategory` has more content then you'll need to use `through`:

[Link to the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through)